# Is it Sunnah of Islam to always make dua?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, sunnah, dua

Does Muhammad S always make alot of dua or little?

My uncle discouraged me to stop nagging Allah.

But, is Scholar Bilal Assad said Allah loves naggers.

Is that also true?

Answer (score 1):

### All perfect praise Be to Allah

Firstly on importance of Dua,

Allaah loves to be asked, and He encourages that in all things. He is angry with the one who does not ask of Him and He encourages His slaves to ask of Him. Allaah says (interpretation of the meaning):

> “And your Lord said: “Invoke Me [i.e. believe in My Oneness (Islamic
>   Monotheism) and ask Me for anything] I will respond to your
>   (invocation)”
>
> [Ghaafir 40:60]

> “O mankind! It is you who stand as beggars in your relation to Allah,
>   and it is Allah Who is Free of all wants, Worthy of all praise.”
>   (Verses, 35:15)
>
> “And when My servants ask Thee (O’ Prophet) about Me, then verily I am
>   near, I answer the prayer (Dua) of the supplicant when he beseeches
>   unto Me. So let them hear My call, and believe in Me, so that they may
>   be led aright.” (Sureh. 2:  Ayat 186)

Du’aa’ is very important in Islam, so much so that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:

> “Du’aa’ is worship.”

Narrated by al-Tirmidhi, 3372; Abu Dawood, 1479; Ibn Maajah, 3828; classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi, 2590.

> "The most excellent worship is du`a." [Sahih Al-Jami` no. 1133];

> "If one does not ask Allah, He will get angry with him."  [Sahih
>   al-Jami` no.2414]

> "Verily your Lord is the One modest and Generous, and when His servant
>   raises his hands to Him in supplication, He is diffident (in some
>   wordings, shy or hesitant) from returning them empty."  [Ahmad, Abu
>   Dawud and at-Tirmidhi - Hasan]

> الدعاء سلاح المؤمن وعماد الدين ونور السموات والأرض “Du‘a is a weapon
>   of a Muslim, a Pillar of Deen and the light of the skies and earth.”
>   [Narrated by Hakim from Sayyiduna Abu Hurayrah and Abu Ya’la from
>   Sayyiduna ‘Ali al-Murtudah, Hadith 6163]

> “A servant’s supplication is never void of three things:
>
> 1) either his sins are forgiven, 2) or he benefits in this world, 3)
>   or virtues are accumulated for him in the hereafter.
>
> When the servant will observe this reward (Thawab) accumulated for him
>   in the hereaftr in compensation for that which was not fulfilled in
>   the Duniyah, then he will desire that none of his desires should have
>   been fulfilled in the world, but rather be accumulated for the
>   hereafter.”

All of these verses and ahadees are so self explanatory that their is nothing left to say.

Additionally it might be the case that their is something regarding your way of du because of which your uncle discourages you, for antiquates of dua read this [link](https://islamqa.info/en/36902)

Now, about dua of prophet,

Prophet S.A.W.W used to pray before and after everything, we find duas for most of the daily matters, besides that he used to make long prays in nights as mentioned in ahadees. And i don't think i can take this answer that long to mention them too here.